# Probability of placing 8 rooks that cannot attack in a chessboard (error in textbook?)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My solution would be $\frac{8!}{64 \choose 8}$ as there are 8 places to put the first rook on the first row, then there are 7 places left on the second row etc etc, then divide this by the total number of ways of choosing 64 squares to occupy with 8 rooks.

Looking elsewhere on this StackExchange, I believe this is correct (this post is slightly different as it's re. probabilities, not just combinations)?

However, the textbook has the following answer:

[image]

I am bamboozled as I believe the denominator is $64 \choose 7$ and the numerator seems to ignore the fact that it doesn't matter the order which the rooks are placed on each row.

Comment: You already have your answers, but let me complement them by adding the (likely) rationale of the author; for the rook number 1, there are 8x8=64 squares, and for the second, there are 7x7 squares and so on and so forth. The denominator is there to tell you how many ways you can put 8 distinguishable rooks onto the board (albeit with a small typo).

Comment: Yeah I think I agree with that rationale, although funnily enough the author slipped up with both the numerator and the denominator...

Comment: I think the numerator is exactly right by that logic? Can you explain why you think numerator is a slip up?

Comment: Ah never mind, I take it you've done an ordered approach where each rook is distinguishable? And yes, the author hasn't slipped up with the numerator as you can write $64 \choose 8$ as $\frac{64*63...*57}{8!}$ and they've moved the 8! to the numerator.

Comment: Yup, I (or rather they) took an ordered approach; no, they said there are $64 \cdot ... \cdot 58$ ways to put ordered rooks onto a chess board. No flipping of things to the numerator; they put $64 P 8$ in the denominator. Did not mean to confuse you; hope this helped.

Comment: Ah I see, no worries! - it's easy to get tangled up trying to figure out whether to go for an unordered or ordered approach.

Comment: Indeed! Thankfully, they generally both work, though sometimes you might need more care with one or the other. (I find the ordered one to be easier in problems where you can allocate your objects one by one)

Comment: Hang on a second - so my denominator is unordered, but my numerator follows and ordered approach? I didn't go for the ordered 'squares' approach, I went for an unordered approach where I go through each row separately (rather than each shrinking square). What is the difference between the squares approach and the row approach? It seems that going for squares -> ordered, rows (my method) -> unordered because it's squares approach divide by 8!. Idk I'm really confused. I might've fluked my answer by mixing up two approaches?

Comment: Calm down, your answer is right! Yours is not really "ordered" in the sense that is used here; you can imagine in your case that you did not actually put them ordered; you put them unordered and looked at their possible locations once all of them were placed. (If you were putting them ordered, note that you would not necessarily put it first row, second row, ...; you would first pick a row (8 choices first, 7 second...) and then put it in an available column, which would give you the $i^2$); does that make sense?

Comment: Ah I think I get it now! Yes your comments in combination w/ Steven's answer below helps to think about ordered vs unordered. I also got muddled to as to why the squares approach is ordered, but I think I get it - we have free reign over which row to place the rook (as long as it's in a non-attacking position), rather than assigning rows to the first, second, third, etc rooks. I also got muddled as I can't count apparently (miscounted the squares method when figuring it out earlier). :)

Comment: Yeah, exactly! Glad I could help! also lol this isnt the forum for it, and I know it is unsolicited, but the expression is "free rein" not "free reign" though it s a very common misspelling. Hope that tidbit also is useful at some point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there is a small typo in the textbook. If you write out ${64\choose 8}=\frac{64!}{(8!)(56!)}$ and then cancel the $56!$ in the denominator from the numerator, you get $\frac{64\cdot63\cdots57}{8!}$; inverting this and multiplying by $8!$ (that is, dividing $8!$ by this) then gives $\frac{(8!)^2}{64\cdot63\cdots57}$ as the probability. But the numerator here can be written as $\prod_{i=1}^8i^2$, by commuting the multiplications. In other words, the book's solution, modulo that typo, is the same as yours.

As has been noted in the comments, these two answers can be interpreted distinctly combinatorially; what you've written — $\dfrac{8!}{64\choose 8}$ is the number of arrangements of 8 (unordered) rooks in non-attacking positions on the chessboard — that is, just the number of permutations of 8 objects, one per row — divided by the total number of arrangements of unordered rooks on the board. Similarly, the book's answer of $\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^8i^2}{64\cdot63\cdots57}$ is the number of arrangement of 8 *ordered* rooks in non-attacking positions divided by the total number of arrangements of ordered rooks on the board; the numerator here can be thought of as placing rook `1` on any of the $8\times8$ squares on the board, then placing rook `2` on any of the $7\times7$ squares that aren't attacked by rook `1`, etc. Another interpretation is that it's the way of arranging unordered rooks in non-attacking configurations (i.e., the $8!$ permutations from your numerator) times the number of ways of ordering those rooks (also $8!$).

Answer (score 1):

The textbook answer given has a small error - the denominator product should run to $57$. Otherwise they are the same number.

$$\frac{8!}{64 \choose 8} = \frac{8!}{\frac{64!}{56!\,8!}} = \frac{8!\,8!}{\frac{64!}{56!}} = \frac{\prod_1^8{i^2}}{64\cdot 63\cdot 62\cdots 57}$$